# Ansible-Inventory AWS_EC2 plugin how to show hostnames and private ips

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

Is there anyway to template hostnames with the aws ec2 plugin? This is my inventory script:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.role
    prefix: aws
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
  - private-ip-address
groups:
    integration: group_names
```

Running `ansible-inventory -i integration.aws_ec2.yml --graph` gives me this

```
@all:
  |--@aws_apilb:
  |  |--apilb001.core.int.ec2.corp.pvt
  |--@aws_bastion:
  |  |--core-bastion
  |  |--ops-bastion
  |  |--webint-bastion-bastion
```

But I want something like this where the private ip is included. I can get one or the other by either removing `tag:Name` or keeping it but I want both.

```
@all:
  |--@aws_apilb:
  |  |--apilb001.core.int.ec2.corp.pvt (10.111.0.111)
  |--@aws_bastion:
  |  |--core-bastion  (10.111.0.112)
  |  |--ops-bastion  (10.111.0.113)
  |  |--webint-bastion-bastion  (10.111.0.113)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if there is a way at this moment (ansible v2.9) to do what you are looking for. However, I could find a pending [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55911) requesting for the similar feature which could be available on ansible v2.10.

In the meantime, you can override the existing plugin as suggested [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55911#issuecomment-565636763).

Answer (score 0):

Use this content for `hostnames`:

```
hostnames:
  - name: 'private-ip-address'
    separator: '_'
    prefix: 'tag:Name'
```

sample output:
`myNameTag_myPrivate_ip`